# Filter out non-numbers from any given argument, Perl beginnings

Tags: perl, replace, argv

Novice programmer here eager to get past this initial hump of, "What do I do?!?!"...

I'm trying to create a Perl script that will take any argument. Then I want the script to return the numbers found in the arguments offered by deleting all non-digits. The output would look something like:

`./numberreturner.pl plal1 pdse2d 30eeee and 5`

Would return `12305`

Any guidance? I have this atm and I am completely clueless where to begin with it.

This script takes any number of `$ARGV`, returns the numbers found by deleting all digits

```
!/usr/bin/perl -w
$digits =~ s/$ARGV
for ($ARGV) return "$digits";
```

As you can see... No idea..

Answer (score 3):

Use `s///` to strip out non-digits (`\D`):

```
s/\D+//g, print for @ARGV;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like no one has mentioned the canonical way to do this which is to use [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) (the relevant section is a couple pages down from that link).

You need the `/c` modifier which complements the character list, and the `/d` modifier, which deletes characters that don't have a corresponding character in the translation list.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = './numberreturner.pl plal1 pdse2d 30eeee and 5';

(my $digits = $str) =~ tr/0-9//cd;

print $digits;
```

**output**

```
12305
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the regexp inside the loop and print the result:

- The `s/[^0-9]//g` will delete all non numeric character inside each `$ARGV` item.
- `$_` correspond to the loop item (Here each passed parameter)

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    for (@ARGV) {
        $_ =~ s/[^0-9]//g;
        print $_;
    }
```

Since you're a beginner, you should consider using `use strict` inside your scripts, it will force you to take good programming habits.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "@ARGV" =~ /\d+/g;
```

will print all digits from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\D` regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "@ARGV";
$str =~ s/\D//g;

print $str;
```

Comment: This will only do the first argument

Comment: You can change $str=shift to $str="@ARGV"

Answer (score 0):

Join all arguments first, then remove all non-digit characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $args = join '', @ARGV;
$args =~ s/\D//g;
print "$args\n";
```